# Cannot intercept context menu item click

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?
When user selects a word and does a right-click he can choose 'Open Wiki-Link' -
that's working fine. But for some reason nothing happens on a click,
the code in `onMessage` is not been executed. Why?

```js
exports.main = function() {

    var tabs = require('tabs');
    //var sel = require('selection');
    var cm = require('context-menu');

    var menuItem = cm.Item({
        label: 'Open Wiki-Link',
        context: cm.SelectionContext(),
        contextScript: 'self.on("click", function() {' +
            'var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
            'self.postMessage(text);' +    
        '});',
        onMessage: function(text) {
            if (text.length === 0) {
                throw ('No text selected');
            }
            tabs.open('http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + text);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct and matches the examples from the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/addon-kit/context-menu.html) pretty closely. I think that the only issue is a typo: it should be `contentScript`, not `contextScript`.